# How to make a long line from a doctest PEP8-compliant?

Tags: python, pep8, doctest, long-lines

I have written a function with a doctest. The doctest contains output that is longer than 79 characters, so a PEP8-checker complains, as it should, that

> simulation.py:267:80: E501 line too long (344 > 79 characters)

```
def walk_depth_order(tree, root_depth=0):
    """Walk a tree in depth order, highest nodes first.

    >>> from newick import loads
    >>> t = lambda x: newick.loads(x)[0]
    >>> intermingled = "((((A:1.9,B:1.8)K:5,(C:4.7,D:4.6)N:2)P:1,(E:2.5,"\\
    ... "F:2.4)L:5)Q:2,((G:5.3,H:5.2)O:3,(I:3.1,J:3.0)M:5)R:1)S;"
    >>> list(walk_tree_depth_order(t(intermingled)))
    [(Node("S"), 0), (Node("R"), 1.0), (Node("Q"), 2.0), (Node("P"), 3.0), (Node("O"), 4.0), (Node("N"), 5.0), (Node("M"), 6.0), (Node("L"), 7.0), (Node("K"), 8.0), (Node("J"), 9.0), (Node("I"), 9.1), (Node("H"), 9.2), (Node("G"), 9.3), (Node("F"), 9.4), (Node("E"), 9.5), (Node("D"), 9.6), (Node("C"), 9.7), (Node("B"), 9.8), (Node("A"), 9.9)]

    """
    ...
```

I would like the continuous-integration test to continue checking for PEP8 violations and I want the doctest to check out, so what should I do?